# Cannot read properties of null (reading 'forEach') problem

Tags: javascript

I was working on the todo list project, but while transferring the values ​​written to the local storage to the UI, I encountered this error. I tried all the suggestions, but I could not do anything. What should I do?

Here is my code:

```
const form = document.querySelector("#todo-form");
const todoInput = document.querySelector("#todo");
const todoList = document.querySelector(".list-group");
const firstCard = document.querySelectorAll(".card-body")[0];
const secondCard = document.querySelectorAll(".card-body")[1];
const filter = document.querySelector("#filter");
const clearButton = document.querySelector("#clear-todos");

eventListeners();

function eventListeners() {
    form.addEventListener("submit", addTodo);
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", loadAllTodosToUI);
}

function loadAllTodosToUI() {
    let todos = getTodosFromStorage();

    todos.forEach(function (todo) {
        addTodoToUI(todo)
    });
}

function addTodo(e) {
    const newTodo = todoInput.value.trim();

    if (newTodo === "") {
        showAlert("danger", "bir todo gir");
    } else {
        addTodoToUI(newTodo);
        addTodoToStorage(newTodo);
        showAlert("success", "başarıyla eklendi");
    }

    e.preventDefault();
}

function getTodosFromStorage() {
    let todos;

    if (localStorage.getItem("todos") === null) {
        todos = [];
    } else {
        todos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(todos));
    }
    return todos;
}

function addTodoToStorage(newTodo) {
    let todos = getTodosFromStorage();

    todos.push(newTodo);

    localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(todos));
}

function showAlert(type, message) {
    const alert = document.createElement("div");

    alert.className = `alert alert-${type}`;

    alert.textContent = message;

    firstCard.appendChild(alert);

    setTimeout(() => {
        alert.remove();
    }, 1000);
}

function addTodoToUI(newTodo) {
    const listItem = document.createElement("li");
    const link = document.createElement("a");
    link.href = "#";
    link.className = "delete-item";
    link.innerHTML = "<i class = 'fa fa-remove'></i>";

    listItem.className = "list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between";

    listItem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(newTodo));
    listItem.appendChild(link);

    todoList.appendChild(listItem);

    todoInput.value = "";
}
```

The console says that there is an error directly related to forEach, but the value I entered in the local storage is not null, but I get this error

Comment: Probably just a typo: `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(todos))` -> `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todos"))`

Comment: Provided that it was not a typo ^^^, you could convert your code to an actually working snippet by adding your HTML and maybe a sprinkle of CSS. Or at least post the exact error message you get pointing exact line of code :)